# Clojure - map a partition over a sequence

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, partitioning

I have two collections of the same size - I have partitioned the first one and would like to apply the same partition to the second one. Is there an elegant way of doing this? I have found the following but it seems ugly...

```
(def x (range 50 70))
(def y [(range 5) (range 10) (range 3) (range 2)] ;my partition of 20 items

(drop-last
  (reduce (fn [a b] (concat (drop-last a)
                            (split-at (count b) (last a))))
          [x] y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would propose a slightly different approach, using the collections manipulation functions:

```
(defn split-like [pattern data]
  (let [sizes (map count pattern)]
    (->> sizes
         (reductions #(drop %2 %1) data)
         (map take sizes))))

user> (split-like y x)
;;=> ((50 51 52 53 54) (55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64) (65 66 67) (68 69))
```

the idea is to collect corresponding tails by `reductions` with `drop`:

```
user> (reductions (fn [acc x] (drop x acc)) (range 20) [1 2 3 4])
;;=> ((0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
;;    (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
;;    (3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
;;    (6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
;;    (10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19))
```

and then just to take needed amounts from that tails:

```
user> (map take [1 2 3 4] *1)
;;=> ((0) (1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8 9))
```

Comment: Marking this as accepted. Quite elegant and on my machine, 20x faster than my or Alan's answer. Thank you both!

Comment: thanks. I wouldn't reason about the performance here though: this one is a lazy, and Alan's one is eager. So, the performance really depends on how would you use the result in the end.

Comment: ah, you're right but i did change the map to a mapv before looking at performance, and added a vec just to be 200% sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar in spirit to your solution, but I think it is easier to read a straightforward `loop/recur` structure than a somewhat unconventional `reduce`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

; we want to partition x into the same shape as y
(verify
  ; ideally should have error checking to ensure have enough x values, etc
  (let [x       (range 50 70)
        y       [(range 5) (range 10) (range 3) (range 2)] ;my partition of 20 items
        lengths (mapv count y)
        x2      (loop [xvals  x
                       lens   lengths
                       result []]
                  (if (empty? lens)
                    result ; return result when no more segments wanted
                    (let [len-curr    (first lens)
                          xvals-next  (drop len-curr xvals)
                          lens-next   (rest lens)
                          result-next (conj result (vec (take len-curr xvals)))]
                      (recur xvals-next lens-next result-next))))]
    (is= lengths [5 10 3 2])
    (is= x2
      [[50 51 52 53 54]
       [55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64]
       [65 66 67]
       [68 69]])))
```

When using `loop/recur`, I quite like the readability of making explicit the `*-next` values that will be passed into the succeeding loop.  I find it unnecessarily difficult to read code that does everything inline in a big, complicated `recur` form.

Also, since Clojure data is immutable, it doesn't matter that I computer `xvals-next` before using the current `xvals` to compute `result-next`.

Built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: that's a nice use of loop/recur! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :as s])
(let [x (range 50 70)
          y [(range 5) (range 10) (range 3) (range 2)]]
        (s/setval [s/ALL (s/subselect s/ALL)] x y))
```

Comment: specter is awesome! )